# Minimum spanning tree in a graph with multiple root vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, directed-graph

I would like to know if there is an algorithm which computes a minimum spanning tree (optimum branching) in a directed graph given a set of root vertices between all of these root vertices, but not only one root vertex and all other vertices in a graph.

Given a set of root vertices [1,4,6] and a graph G like the one on the following picture:

[image]

...the algorighm should return something like a green sub-graph on the same picture.

I would like to get such an MST that connects all the root vertices provided to the algorithm. I tend to think that the result of the would-be algorithm is a sub-graph of the graph G which contains all root vertices and some other vertices from G.

Notes:

1. I know that there is no MST for a directed graph, but there is [Chu–Liu/Edmonds algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu%E2%80%93Liu/Edmonds_algorithm).
2. I guess that a result of such an algorithm (if it is actually possible) will return an optimum branching, which includes some vertices of a graph along with all root vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimum Spanning Trees are supposed to span all the vertices. I think you might be actually dealing with a [Steiner Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem#Generalization_of_minimum_spanning_tree) problem, given that you only need to connect a subset of them. Unfortunately, the traditional Steiner tree problem with undirected edges is already NP complete so you have a tough road ahead of you.